# Windows Phone 8.1 App - Auto Logout (Detect if App is Running)

Tags: windows, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light, win-universal-app

I am building a Windows 8.1 Universal app, and at the minute specifically I am working on the Windows Phone side of it. The app is an RT app built using the MVVM pattern, and I am using MVVM Light.

The app is for a financial institunion and exposes payment information. As such, there is a security requirement to log the user out of the app if there is no activity after a period of 2 minutes.

I've searched high and low for a solution to this problem. The only one which really works is to set up gestures in the view, and use a DispatchTimer, which expires and redirects to the app lock screen (not the built-in Windows one) after 2 minutes if no gestures have been detected. A gesture resets the timer. Here is some sample code for the gesture setup:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();                      

        //Register the gestures, for the app timeout
        this.PointerPressed += MainPage_PointerPressed;
        this.PointerMoved += MainPage_PointerMoved;
        this.PointerReleased += MainPage_PointerReleased;
        gr.CrossSliding += Gr_CrossSliding;
        gr.Dragging += Gr_Dragging;
        gr.Holding += Gr_Holding;
        gr.ManipulationCompleted += Gr_ManipulationCompleted;
        gr.ManipulationInertiaStarting += Gr_ManipulationInertiaStarting;
        gr.ManipulationStarted += Gr_ManipulationStarted;
        gr.ManipulationUpdated += Gr_ManipulationUpdated;
        gr.RightTapped += Gr_RightTapped;
        gr.Tapped += Gr_Tapped;
        gr.GestureSettings = Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationRotate | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateX | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateY |
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationScale | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationRotateInertia | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationScaleInertia |
        Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.ManipulationTranslateInertia | Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.Tap;

        InitializeTimer();
    }
```

There are methods for receiving gesture inputs on the page, like this:

```
private void Gr_Tapped(Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer sender, Windows.UI.Input.TappedEventArgs args)
    {
        ResetTimer();
    }
```

And here is my timer code:

```
private DispatcherTimer _timer2 { get; set; }
    int ticks = 0;

    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        _timer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer2.Tick += timer2_Tick;
        _timer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(00, 0, 1);
        bool enabled = _timer2.IsEnabled;
        _timer2.Start();
    }

    void timer2_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        ticks++;            

        if (ticks >= 120)
        {
            Timeout();
        }
    }

    private void Timeout()
    {
        _timer2.Stop();
        _timer2 = null;

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(LockView));
    }

    private void ResetTimer()
    {
        _timer2.Stop();
        _timer2.Start();

        ticks = 0;
    }
```

This solution is far from perfect. I will have to use it if I can't find a better one, but there are 4 main problems with it;

1. It breaks the MVVM pattern. All this code has to go in the code behind of the View. I have 7 views which are accessible after the user logs in, so there will be a lot of repitition
2. It doesn't capture all gestures. For example is seems to ignore when scrolling up and down a listbox full of items
3. I have to call the ResetTimer() method or _timer2.Stop() from anywhere in the view that might be considered a gesture (even just before navigating away from the view)
4. It's just a messy and awkward solution

Does anyone know of a better way of achieving this? Surely there's a more elegant solution, maybe something at a higher level, rather than trying to catch every last button press and gesture.

Also, it would be useful if the app could detect whether it was running in the foreground or the background, and auto-navigates to the lock screen if the user navigates away from the app then goes back to it later.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions...

Comment: The last part of your question can be easily done by subscribing to the Application `Suspended` and `Resumed` applications, and check the time elapsed between them

Comment: As for your first point, you don't have to duplicate your code, just create a class that inherit from PhoneApplicationPage, put your stuff in it, and make all your pages inherit from that new class.

Comment: Last but not least, MVVM is about separating business logic from UI logic. User interaction should be handled by the view, while the VM handles the resulting the actions. There's nothing that says "you can't use the codebehind file", it's just a good practice to make sure that nobody will be tempted to put business logic in there. The gesture listener has its place there. But yes, once recognized, either the "a gesture happened" or the "no gesture since xx seconds" (your choice) event should be bubbled up to the VM and handled there. Whether the xx seconds is a business rule is open to debate

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up using that solution, but sharing the timer object between all the classes. It works well enough